# how call custom protocol by javascript multiple time

Tags: javascript, protocols

I have a custom protocol that run a exe file in windows and i wanna call it multiple times in client side by javascript. but problem is that just first one called,
consider the following code

```
function init() {
    doIt(1);
    doIt(2);
}
function doIt(data) {
    let openCash = "localPrinters:" + data;
    let ahref = document.createElement('a');
    ahref.href = openCash;
    ahref.click();
}
init();
```

I wanna call this protocol multiple times, and it calls just by first one
is there a way to call it multiple time ?